# Неактивная кнопка "Добавить в корзину", если в корзине уже есть товар WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Я использую код, который меняет у товара текст кнопки "Добавить в корзину", если данный товар уже есть в корзине.

```
/* Меняем текст кнопки для страниц каталога, категорий товаров */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'new_products_button_text', 20, 2 );
 
function new_products_button_text( $text, $product ) {
 
    if( 
       $product->is_type( 'simple' )
       && $product->is_purchasable()
       && $product->is_in_stock()
       && WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $product->get_id() ) )
    ) {
 
        $text = 'Товар в корзине';
 
    }
 
    return $text;
 
}

/* Меняем текст кнопки для страницы товара */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'new_single_product_button_text' );
 
function new_single_product_button_text( $text ) {
 
    if( WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( get_the_ID() ) ) ) {
        $text = 'Товар в корзине';
    }
 
    return $text;
 
}
```

Подскажите, как можно сделать кнопку с новым текстом "Товар в корзине" неактивной, если данный товар уже в корзине?

У меня включен AJAX, при добавлении в корзину и тут возникает еще одна проблема. Если я добавляю товар в корзину, то текст "Товар в корзине" показывается только после перезагрузки страницы.

Как можно показать новый текст и сделать кнопку неактивной сразу после первого добавления в корзину? Сразу оговорюсь, функционал "продавать индивидуально", тут не подходит.

**UPDATE:**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'disable_add_to_cart_if_product_is_in_cart', 10, 2 );
function disable_add_to_cart_if_product_is_in_cart ( 
   $is_purchasable, $product ){
  
    if(WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $product->get_id() ) )) {
        return false;
    }
    
    return $is_purchasable;
}
```

Я также добавлял этот код, но на странице каталога у кнопки "Товар в корзине" меняется текст на "Подробнее" и появляется новая ссылка, ведущая на страницу этого продукта. На странице товара кнопка "Товар в корзине" просто исчезает.

С кнопкой "Добавить в корзину", если товар не добавлен, все в порядке.

Есть ли другие варианты кода, которые могут помочь в моем вопросе?

Буду рад вашей помощи!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете через этот фильтр проверить наличие товара в корзине

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'disable_add_to_cart_if_product_is_in_cart', 10, 2 );
function disable_add_to_cart_if_product_is_in_cart ( 
   $is_purchasable, $product ){
  
    if(WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $product->get_id() ) )) {
        return false;
    }
    
    return $is_purchasable;
}
```

По поводу замены текста в кнопке после добавления товара в корзину, у wc есть js ивенты которые он тригерит после этого действия, если ваш функционал для ajax добавления в корзину так же их тригерит то вы можете обновить текст кнопки после этого ивента

```
$( document.body ).on( 'added_to_cart', function(){
     console.log('added_to_cart');
});
```

Comment: К сожалению, я уже пробовал данный вариант, при котором на странице каталога у кнопки "Товар в корзине" меняется текст на "Подробнее" и новая ссылка с кнопки ведет на страницу товара. На самой странице товара, кнопка добавления в корзину просто исчезла. Я обновил свой вопрос.